# Login name should appear in the textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Using VB.NET

Windows Based Application

In my software I am using a login page, with a textbox for username.

First time am entering the username and password in my software, next time I run my software the last entered username should automatically appear in the login page.

In VB.net, How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to persist the name between program sessions.  This is typically done using `My.Settings`.

I assume you're using Winforms, since you didn't mention ASP.NET.

**Using My.Settings in Visual Basic 2005** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Using windows Based Application.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using Database in your Software?? If it is so, then u can store the username in your database which you logged in recently and then retreive it when you are opening the software..